# Menu floating to the right on IE and to the left in FF

Tags: css, css-float

I am working on a website that has a menu which behaves correctly on FF but not on IE (as usuall).
On IE it floats to the right while it should float to the left, however if float is set to none it behaves almost correctly, attaching the  onto the top of the container.
[Here's a live example.](http://simply-cdn.plutog.co.il/)
Here's the css:

```
/* Navigation */
.navigation
{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 650px;
}

.navigation ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 8px 0 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation ul li
{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

.navigation ul li.last
{
    border: none;
}

.navigation ul li a
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.navigation ul li a.active
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn_login
{
    float: right;
    margin: 4px 4px 0 0;
    display: inline;
    width: 200px;
}
```

And here's the html:

```
<div id="navigation_wrap">
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="default.asp">Home Page</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="faq.asp">FAQ</a></li><li><a class="" href="articles.asp">Articles</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="products.asp">Packages &amp; Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a class="" href="gp.asp?gpid=15">test1</a></li>
                    <li><a class=" last" href="gp.asp?gpid=17">test asher</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="btn_login">
              ...
            </div>
</div>
```

I hope anyone would have an idea.
Thanks,
Omer.

EDIT:
Setting the width for both elements kinda helped but it's still not positioned correctly.
See updated css above.

Comment: Edited... Forgot to add the link.

Comment: not sure why the extra markup for class="" = empty classes?

Comment: Just because of classic ASP, I can remove it but it should have no effect

Comment: I read the title, and now I've got Stealer's Wheel in my head... =/

Comment: @ricebowl: LOL, found the solution finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try reducing the height of your logo class. It is overhanging the menu.

Comment: That works but then it's too small. it's only 99px high.
Any other way to fix this?

Comment: Reducing the height of the logo by 9 px and defining the widths for both divs worked.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just got back from lunch - glad you've fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

<-span class=""top_nav_separator""> is in your code, this might be the thing that bothers IE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IE some time ago.  It doesn't like list items in a floating div.  Adding the following fixed it for me:

```
display: list-item;
list-style-position: inside;
```

Comment: In which tags should I put them?

Comment: Place them in the li tags in your css.
li{
       display: list-item;
       list-style-position: inside;
}

Comment: It doesn't seem to effect anything.